# Movie where street becomes a mirror world with copies of people?

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I am looking for the title of a horror movie. This is what I remember from it:

It starts out with a bunch of young people in a house, I believe they are having a party. At one point they find a box(?) on the door step to the house. They don't know how it got there, but it turns out later that a mirror copy of two(?) of the people in the house put it there.

Occasionally, some of the people leave the house and walk the street. I think they go through a particularly "dark spot" on the street, and they come back to the house that they left. Or so they think anyway, because it is really a mirror copy of the house that they left, and they can see their friends and themselves inside.

Both the people from the original house and the people from the house in the mirror world somehow get the idea that the people from the other house are evil, and they begin to plot how to get rid of them.

I also think that I recall that one of the people's father is an expert in a science-ish field, and it is implied that the whole mixing of dimensions happens because some celestial object, maybe a meteor, is particularly close to Earth.

I hope this rings a bell for someone.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed plot description. Year & country also often help in these things.

Comment: @Walt no problem. From the movie trailer, I see now that only some of the people attending the party can convincingly be said to be young. Thanks for your answer, I had been googling and browsing IMDB for an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're describing the plot of [Coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(film)) from 2013.

> Three couples — Emily and Kevin, Hugh and Beth, Amir and Laurie — attend a dinner party hosted by their friends Mike and Lee. At the party, they mention the passing comet which has been on the news for a while. Everyone notices their cell phone and laptop losing receptions. Emily talks about strange phenomena recorded in Finland after a comet passed in 1923. Hugh wants to contact his brother, a physicist who had warned him about odd effects from the comet.
>
> A blackout then occurs. Hugh and Amir head to another house a few blocks away still has power for a working telephone. After power is restored, Hugh and Amir return, carrying a box which they had found at the other house. Hugh explains that he saw in the other house a dinner table set exactly like theirs. In the box are a ping pong paddle and several photos. The group is alarmed to find that each photo has one of them in it and a number on the back. Amir notes that the photo of him was taken that night, inside the house, and Emily realizes that the numbers are written in her handwriting.

The plot is quite convoluted. Here's the trailer: